# CSS Image size auto makes tracking pixels appear as missing images

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for a site. Apparently bootstrap defaults all images to width and height = 100%.

The site includes ads from an ad server, which include tracking pixels to track impressions etc. These pixel images have inline sizes of 0, but the css style overrides this.

The problem comes in that sometimes the img pixels are not valid image files, and so the images shows up with the little "x" in a box to shoe the image is missing. Since there is no way to know the "real" size of this image, the browser shows a little box, maybe 15 or 20 pixels square.

I've added styles for some pixels that identify them by name and set their sizes back to 0, but now I have a pixel that doesn't have a name or ID I can reference.

What I need to do is "erase" the default "auto" image size from at least the containers the ads are in. I don't want to remove this from the bootstrap css files, as this will just break any time I upgrade (as well as potentially break other bootstrap features).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3? BS3 should only put a max-width:100% on img with a `.img-responsive` tag or if it's part of `.carousel`, `.thumbnail` or `@media print` style. BS3 shouldn't touch height at all.  As a matter fact, you might find height to be funky on responsive designs because it uses `max-width:100%` instead of just `width:100%` which can cause some background to come through at different sizes.  And I don't recall Bootstrap 2 defaulting images to 100% either. Did anyone customize the Bootstrap LESS before using it?

Comment: Looks like this one is an older 2.x version. so seems 3 fixes this issue then...

Answer (score 1):

If you have 'rich' HTML banners you should **always** load them in an iframe. Not only does this make them insensitive to the CSS of the main page as illustrated by your problem, and in reverse ensures they don't break your own layout, it also prevents a lot of possible XSS exploits. Don't trust third party code in your application, neither for maintaining layout nor for being secure.

Another advantage of the iframe approach is that external resources, such as images, used by the banners may often load slowly from central CDNs, and are deferred by the iframe to load last after the containing page is loaded - so ads can never slow down your user experience.

There is really, apart from framing, no other way to reliably cancel 'some' CSS for just a few container elements - it's just not what CSS is supposed to do, its whole purpose is to be global for the entire document.

Comment: I've given a script to run for an ad server. No control over this, except to no longer run then.

Comment: I'll try running them inside an iframe though and see if it works, thanks

Comment: Even if just for maintainability I'd advise on this approach - just having a separate `banners` folder and linking them from the main code is so much easier than always editing the master templates.

Comment: the ads are served via a single included javascript file, so there is no maintenance.